# Cross-launching other apps from iOS actionable notifications

Tags: ios, iphone, ios8, notifications, launcher

Is it possible to cross-launch another - not my - app from an `iOS 8` actionable notification?
So user swipes the notification and then tap on one of the two buttons to open a 3rd party app.
Is that possible and how?
Couldn't find any documentation.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The button directly opening the 3rd party app without opening your app first, NO but the button could be programmed to open your app and then launch the 3rd party app.

For this to be possible the other app must have URL scheme implemented in their app. You will need to find out if the app has URL scheme implemented. If they do you can use something like this below.

```
NSURL *myURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"APPURLSCHEME://"];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:myURL];
```

You will replace APPURLSCHEME with whatever the apps url scheme is. LinkedIn for example is linkedin:// .

Comment: Here is a tutorial on actionable notificaitons https://nrj.io/simple-interactive-notifications-in-ios-8. The last code box is where you implement your button actions. You would add the above code to that button action.

Comment: It won't be possible to open the other app directly from the notification, only your app can be be opened, but then immediately you can launch the other app.